# Disable bold font in 'top' command

Tags: top, watch-command

I want to have a custom 'watch' command that also includes the output of a single round of `top -n 1`, but the escape characters do not translate well. Is there a way to disable the bold font of the top command in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-b` ("Batch-mode operation"):

```
top -b -n1
```

Comment: This will output _many_ lines. This can be restricted with the `-w` switch together with the `LINES` environment variable: `LINES=20 top -b -w -n1` shows max. 20 lines.

Comment: This does exactly what i need. A clean output without any escape characters. Thank you!